# systemd-networkd 'relaytarget' not working (dhcp relay) in Debian stable 12 bookworm

Tags: linux, systemd, dhcp

my first question here.

I'm currently using the 'dhcp-helper' program to do dhcp relay, works fine, but I want to switch to using the systemd-networkd 'RelayTarget' function in the *.network file.  I've tried every option I can think of, but can't seem to get it working.

- Running current Debian stable "bookworm 12" 6.1.0-13-amd64
- Debian stable runs systemd 252 (252.17-1~deb12u1)

I've tried every option I can think of, no luck yet.

/etc/systemd/network/02-port2-lan0-static.network:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/02-port2-lan0-static.network
# configures lan0 with static ip address
#
[Match]
Name=lan0
[Network]
Address=172.16.1.1/24
# do not set gateway or dns, will inherit from system
[DHCPServer]
ServerAddress=172.16.11.2/24
RelayTarget=172.16.11.2
BindToInterface=no
```

Anyone have this working in Debian stable?  I realize Debian stable does not run the latest systemd version.  This is a production router, so upgrading to testing is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With this `ServerAddress=`, you're telling networkd to *become* 172.16.11.2 and to relay all DHCP requests *back to itself.* Do not set ServerAddress= at all, or set it to 172.16.1.1/24 (i.e. the router's own address).

Comment: I've tried every combo I can think of, started with just the RelayTarget line, then added the others, none of it worked.